# No Text showing in dateentry field

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I have put multiple dateentry widgets into a single frame, and after doing so, no date appears in the entry field. I have tried to use the .set method using the textvariable that I have set, but that does not work also. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
 # Received Checkbox and date
    receivedBool = tkinter.IntVar()
    receivedBox = tkinter.Checkbutton(status_frame, text="Received", font=h2, variable=receivedBool, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    receivedBox.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(0, 10), sticky='w')
    receivedBox['bg'] = blue
    
    receivedEntry = tkinter.StringVar()
    receivedDate = DateEntry(status_frame, font=h2, selectmode='day', textvariable=receivedEntry)
    receivedDate.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ew')

    
    courseBool = tkinter.IntVar()
    courseBox = tkinter.Checkbutton(status_frame, text="Course Started", font=h2, variable=courseBool, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    courseBox.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(0, 10), sticky='w')
    courseBox['bg'] = blue
    
    courseEntry = tkinter.StringVar()
    courseDate = DateEntry(status_frame, font=h2, selectmode='day', textvariable=courseEntry, date_pattern='dd/MM/yyyy')
    courseDate.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ew')
```

I tried removing additional ones, and this is how it appears. This is what is shown when there is two in the frame.

[image]

Comment: I can see the date in those `DateEntry` widgets.

Comment: @acw1668 Weird. For me what happens is you cannot see the data, but then if you click into the box the data can be seen

Comment: @acw1668 I've attached a picture so you can get a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I had used the string var variable elsewhere it, the date would then show up. For example, for course entry if I put print(courseEntry.get()) somewhere in the program.